# What does this means in this context ? 占い師と騎士を同じにされては困る (MC is worry about a knight when she's about to leave the city at sunset )

Tags: meaning, reading-comprehension, japanese-to-english, conversations

There's a sentence which i'm not sure about its meaning when reading. Hope someone can explains to me the correct meaning , if my understanding was wrong.

Context: MC is worry about a knight when she's about to leave the city at sunset. And also there are orcs outside the city walls, they're hunting only woman lately.

MC「でもこんな時間に出発して、本当に大丈夫なのか？」

俺は少し真面目に訊ねた。

MC「もう日も落ちてきている。夕奈は、夜明けと同時に出ていたくらいなのに」

**Female Knight「夕奈……？　あぁ、あの占い師か。占い師と騎士を同じにされては困る」**
(my guess: "...You shouldn't think a fortune teller/ diviner and a knight like me are on the same league." but i'm not sure )

Answer (score 2):

For the sentence per se, your understanding is correct.

The preceding question of MC suggests that the speaker won't arrive in time leaving (as late as) around the evening. The bold part implies that a knight like her is not as slow as a fortune teller and can make it (even if leaving much later than the fortune teller).

Comment: 多分間に合うかどうかではなく、夜は危険だ的な意味の会話かなと…